# Understand min, max, meshgrid functions to plot MED boundary in pattern recognition

Tags: matlab, pattern-recognition

This code is correct But, I don't understand what is the relationship of using `min`, `max` and `meshgrid` functions with plotting of MED contour of two classes. 
I hope my question is clear...... thanks

```
%% Computing the classifiers
step = 0.2; % The lower this is the smoother the contours.
x = min([samples_a(:,1);samples_b(:,1)])-1:step:max([samples_a(:,1);samples_b(:,1)])+1;
y = min([samples_a(:,2);samples_b(:,2)])-1:step:max([samples_a(:,2);samples_b(:,2)])+1;
[X1, Y1] = meshgrid(x,y);

x = min([samples_c(:,1);samples_d(:,1);samples_e(:,1)])-1:step:max([samples_c(:,1);samples_d(:,1);samples_e(:,1)])+1;
y = min([samples_c(:,2);samples_d(:,2);samples_e(:,2)])-1:step:max([samples_c(:,2);samples_d(:,2);samples_e(:,2)])+1;
[X2, Y2] = meshgrid(x,y);

% Plotting the MED boundaries
contour(X1,Y1,MED1, [0, 0], 'Color', 'magenta', 'LineWidth', LINE_WIDTH);
```

Comment: What is it that you don't understand? Do you know what each of these functions do? You can type `help max` or `help meshgrid` in MATLAB to read the function's documentation.

Comment: thanks for help Cris..... but i mean what is the relationship of using min,max with meshgrid and even i read help function's documentation i did not get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

In this code, `x` and `y` are vectors that go from the lowest x and y coordinates in `samples_a` and `samples_b` to the highest. `[samples_a(:,1);samples_b(:,1)]` contains all x-coordinates in the two sets, `min` and `max` take their minimum and maximum values. Supposedly, these then correspond to the locations for the samples in the `MED1` matrix. Thus, the value at `MED1(i,j)` has coordinates `x(j)` and `y(i)`.

You can now do

```
contour(x,y,MED1)
```

The code the uses `meshgrid` to convert these vectors into full matrices `X1` and `Y1`. These two matrices should have the same size as matrix `MED1`, and are defined by replicating the vectors `x` and `y`. Now the value at `MED1(i,j)` has coordinates `X1(i,j)` and `Y1(i,j)`.

You can now do

```
contour(X1,Y1,MED1)
```

in the same way as you could before. The call to `meshgrid` is not necessary.